# Karate core dependency issue in maven project

Tags: java, maven, karate

I am trying to create a maven project using archetype for Karate framework. I have Java 17 and below is snapshot of project creation.
[image]

This creates project successfully but it fails in sync with below issue.

[image]

This looks to be issue on my machine only as on others machine its working and I am not able to figure it out what settings I am missing. Can someone knows about this issue plz?

Below is the POM.

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>karate-testing</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.11.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0</maven.surefire.version>
    <karate.version>1.4.1</karate.version>
</properties>    

<dependencies>         
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>          
    </plugins>        
</build>
```

Comment: Did you maybe set anything in your settings.xml?

Comment: I haven't touched anything else. Is there a way to reset it?

Comment: There is one observation that while create a project, when I select Catalog as "Maven Central" then no archetypes are getting autoloaded. And the machine on which it works, this list is getting populated. Now I am not sure why that list not populating on my machine.

Comment: Have you tried building the project from the command line?

Comment: yes. that also did not help

Comment: Can you add the entire pom.xml?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256024/discussion-between-parashuram-and-reg).

Comment: most likely your local maven repo (cache) is corrupted. just remove the `~/.m2/repository/com/intuit/karate` folder and try again - where `~` is your user home folder

Comment: Thanks Peter for the suggestion as many others also suggested the same but unfortunately that has also not helped.

Comment: don't use the archetype then, use the github template, it is the same thing: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-template

Comment: Great, this has worked. Thanks!